# Pop Under Code - Embedded Video

Tags: javascript, html, popup

How do I add this pop under code to an embedded video, so when the user clicks on the video, it opens a pop under?

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adcash.com/script/java.php? 
option=rotateur&rotateur=123456"></script>
```

If I add this code into my main video site html code, it works perfectly. But it won't work for the embedded html video code (when users implement my video player on their sites).

It is implemented perfectly here : http://played.to/embed-2vi8uyqlm37w-640x360.html.

Comment: Tried this `document.write('<scr'+'ipt type="text/javascript" src="http://www.adcash.com/script/java.php?option=rotateur&rotateur=123456"></scr'+'ipt>');` It's HTML5